# Jest mocking - How do I mock this module..?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, sharp

I'm trying to mock [sharp](http://sharp.dimens.io) and I have this:

```
// /__mocks__/sharp.js

const Sharp = jest.genMockFromModule('sharp')

Sharp.prototype.jpeg = function (options) { return this }
Sharp.prototype.trim = function (options) { return this }
Sharp.prototype.normalise = function (bln) { return this }
Sharp.prototype.background = function (colour) { return this }
Sharp.prototype.embed = function () { return this }
Sharp.prototype.clone = function () { return this }
Sharp.prototype.resize = function (width, height) { return this }

Sharp.prototype.toBuffer = function () {
  return Buffer.from('')
}

export default Sharp
```

When I `import sharp from 'sharp'` and `console.log(sharp)` I get:

`function Sharp() {return mockConstructor.apply(this,arguments);}`

Seems right, it's found my mock module, not the real module.

You use `sharp` like this:

```
const sharpImage = sharp(input, options).jpeg(options).trim()
const myImageBuff = await sharpImage.toBuffer()
```

However, when I call `sharp()` from test code, using my mocked module, it's value is `undefined`, rather than an `instanceof sharp`.

I've tried replacing `const Sharp = jest.genMockFromModule('sharp')` with `function Sharp (input, options) { return this }` but that makes no difference.

What am I doing wrong..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in the `sharp` constructor function.

https://github.com/lovell/sharp/blob/35117239144dcd085ecf653697df725b2f2e8fbb/lib/constructor.js#L97

So I switched out `const Sharp = jest.genMockFromModule('sharp')` for:

```
function Sharp (input, options) {
  if (!(this instanceof Sharp)) {
    return new Sharp(input, options)
  }
  return this
}
```

Seems to work...